# Proof that a Markov Operator's Domain and Codomain are the same

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I am having trouble coming up with a simple proof that $\psi$**M**$\in\Delta(S) $, where $\Delta(S)$ is the set of probabilities over finite set S, **M** is a Markov operator and $\psi\in\Delta(S)$.

For reference, this is exercise 4.3.1 of the book **Economic Dynamics: Theory and Computation** by John Stachurski.

I don't usually post here so if the question needs further information/clarification please do let me know and I will edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\psi \in \Delta(S)$ and a Markov operator $M$.  We can consider $\psi$ as a row vector (nonnegative and summing to one) and $M$ as a square matrix with nonnegative entries and such that the rows sum to 1.  We need to show that $\psi M$ is a nonnegative vector that sums to one.

It's clear that $\psi M$ is nonnegative, since products and sums of nonnegative numbers are nonnegative.

Now let $\mathbf 1$ be a column vector of ones.  We have, using the properties of $\psi$ and $M$, both $\psi \mathbf 1 = 1$ and $M \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$.  Hence

$$ \psi M \mathbf 1 = 1 .  $$

In other words, $\psi$ sums to one and the proof is done.

Comment: God, what a nice and simple way to do it. Also, I would like to point out that the book is amazing and I have greatly and thoroughly enjoyed it, thanks!